# how to add different error to redux-form field on different action

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

My redux form has two action, one is onclick i need to validate only one field and in second action i need to do submit action. How can i achieve this

```
class BLoginForm extends React.PureComponent{
render(){
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting, onSubmit, openForgotForm } = this.props;
    return (
        <FormCon>
            <form onSubmit = { handleSubmit(onSubmit) }>
                <Field name = "username" type = "text" component = { BInputPhone } label = "Email or Mobile number" />
                <Field name = "password" type = "password" component = { BInput } label = "Password" />
                <a onClick = { openForgotForm } >forgot</a>
                <div>
                    <BPrimaryBtn type = "submit" disabled = { submitting }>LOGIN</BPrimaryBtn>
                </div>
            </form>
        </FormCon>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To understsand, I have 3 differents forms.

```
function submitForms() {
  dispatch(submit('FirstOne'))  // First form
  dispatch(submit('secondOne')) // Second form
  dispatch(submit('thirdOne'))  // Thrid form
}
<Button type="button" onClick={ submitForms } />
```

With this function, you'll trigg the submit function to all forms.

You can implement each submit to *dispatch multiple actions*

```
const mapstateToProps = (state,ownProps) => {
  {... do some stuff ... }

return {
  submit : (values, dispatch, props) => {
         dispatch(YOUR ACTIONS) // So to validate one field ?
         dispatch(YOUR ACTIONS) // dispatch your second actions.
    }
 }


export default Form = connect(mapStateToProps)(reduxForm({
  form:'YoURFORMNAME'
})(YoURFORMCOMP))
```

I can add that if you want to validate only fews fields of your form, you can create a simple validate as

```
const required = value => (value ? undefined : 'Required')
```

and add it to your Field as

```
<Field {...props}
    validate={required}
</Field>
```

Comment: I meant I have one form and two buttons, and that two buttons responsible to do two different tasks and both the buttons will do some basic validation before some i/o call. on clicking "forgot", I have to do validation and on submit, the validation is taken care by the redux form itself.

Comment: I do not understand.

Is your validation 'redux-form validation' ? Or other Redux customs actions validations ?

Comment: on clicking forgot I wanna do some custom validation